# Call non-default constructor as member initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I have a class "A", and a class "B" such that A contains an instance of B

```
class A
{
    B b = B(parameters...);
    Other thing = 3;
}
```

The problem with this code, is that B does not (and should not!) have a copy constructor, so the compiler is complaining
I would like to be able to call B's constructor like below, but it interprets it as a function declaration

```
class A
{
    B b(parameters...);
    Other thing = 3;
}
```

Is there a way to call the non-default constructor in the definition of the class?

Comment: In C++17, you could just do `B b = B(parameters...);` like you want.

Comment: @Barry That is nice to know! Thanks. Sadly I am not using C++17.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Default member initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) only supports brace or equals initializer; you could use brace initializer here.

```
class A
{
    B b{parameters...};
    Other thing = 3;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make the copy constructor not visible you can make it `private`

```
Class B
{
     public:
     B(parameters...){};

     private:
     B(B b){};
}
```

As for your code i think your problem is that you need to initiate the member in the constructor of A like this:

```
 class A
{
    A()
      : B(parameters...)
    {
        thing = 3;
    }

    B b;
    Other thing;
}
```

Comment: Maybe less modern, but still easy to write, read and understand. The only drawback is the duplication between declaration of members and initialization in constructor. The reason why `Other thing = 3;` was added in C++11...